# How do I write a dispatch routine in Java?

Tags: java, endpoint, dispatch, requestdispatcher

I need to write a dispatch routine in java that will take strings as input and output the given method (in string format) they correspond to. The strings would represent endpoints, so something like `/guest/leaderboard` would direct me to the guestLeaderboards method. It should also handle wildcards, so something like `/guests/xxxxx/leaderboard` would still take me to the guestLeaderboards (does not need to do anything with the wildcard right now).

I've never done anything like this. I'm looking for examples.

Thanks!

Edit: Been thinking about this a bit more.. could I use a tree where each leaf represents a possible endpoint or method. The algorithm would traverse through the tree based on the tokenized input, where each token is a string between the `/` but only if it matches my list of keywords (if it doesn't it would be considered a wildcard and thrown out)

Comment: suppose this [examaple](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dispatcherservlet) post may be helpful to you.